ASP.NET MVC : in-memory cache GetOrStore
I am trying to Cache some endpoints but in this example I am always going to the database. Do I need to setup the TemplatesDataService.GetTemplateAgentKeyDiseaseId a different way?
 [HttpGet]
 public IHttpActionResult TemplatesUsingDiseaseId(string key, Guid? DiseaseId)
 {
     GuardKey(key);

     IEnumerable<Core.Models.Templates.TemplatesJoinAgent> Templates = null;

     Templates = CacheExtensions.GetOrStore(_cache, templateKey, TemplatesDataService.GetTemplateAgentKeyDiseaseId(null, DiseaseId));

     var result = Templates
                 .Select(t => new
                 {
                     TemplateId = TemplateId(t.TemplateIdMain, t.TemplateIdNumeric, t.TemplateIdAlt),
                     RegimenTitle = t.TemplateTitle,
                     CourseTitle = t.GroupTitle,
                     GuidelineTitle = t.GuideLineTitle,
                     DiseaseId = t.ExternalDiseaseId,
                     DiseaseName = t.DiseaseName,
                     VersionKey = t.VersionKey,
                     PdfUrl = GetPdfUrlVersionKey(t.VersionKey),
                     AgentVersionKey = t.AgentVersionKey,
                     AgentList = t.Agents,
                     AgentName = AgentDisplayName(t.AgentName, t.AgentRxNormTallMan, t.AgentNccnTallMan),
                     IndicationSentences = t.Indication.Where(i => i.ParentId == null).Select(CompileIndicationSentence),
                     PublishedDate = (t.Modified ?? t.Added).ToCommonDateString(),
                     Indications = t.Indications,
                     RelatedAgents = relatedagentsList
                 })
                 .ToList();


     return Json(result.ToList());
 }

CacheExtensions
public static T GetOrStore<T>(this Cache cache, string key, T obj)
 {
     return cache.GetOrStore(key, obj, DefaultCacheExpiration);
 }

 public static T GetOrStore<T>(this Cache cache, string key, T obj, double expireInMinutes)
 {
     var result = cache[key];

     if (result == null)
     {

         lock (sync)
         {
             result = cache[key];
             if (result == null)
             {
                 result = obj != null ? obj : default(T);
                 cache.Insert(key, result, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expireInMinutes), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
             }
         }
     }

     return (T)result;
 }

GetTemplateAgentKeyDiseaseId
public IEnumerable<TemplatesJoinAgent> GetTemplateAgentKeyDiseaseId(Guid? agentKey, Guid? diseaseId)
{
    //Common part
    var TemplatesJoinAgentList = (from t in UnitOfWork.GetRepository<Template>().Get(t => t.IsCurrentVersion &&
                                  t.Status == (short)TemplateMode.Published && (diseaseId == null || t.ExternalDiseaseId == diseaseId))
                                  join r in UnitOfWork.GetRepository<Regimen>().Get() on t.Id equals r.TemplateId
                                  join rp in UnitOfWork.GetRepository<RegimenPart>().Get() on r.Id equals rp.RegimenId
                                  join re in UnitOfWork.GetRepository<RegimenEntry>().Get() on rp.Id equals re.RegimenPartId
                                  join a in UnitOfWork.GetRepository<Agent>().Get(a => a.IsCurrentVersion && a.IsActive && (agentKey == null || a.VersionKey == agentKey)) on re.AgentVersionKey equals a.VersionKey
                                  select new TemplatesJoinAgent
                                  {
                                      TemplateIdMain = t.TemplateIdMain,
                                      TemplateIdNumeric = t.TemplateIdNumeric,
                                      TemplateIdAlt = t.TemplateIdAlt,
                                      TemplateTitle = t.Title,
                                      GroupTitle = t.GroupTitle,
                                      GuideLineTitle = t.GuideLineTitle,
                                      ExternalDiseaseId = t.ExternalDiseaseId,
                                      DiseaseName = t.DiseaseName,
                                      VersionKey = t.VersionKey,
                                      AgentRxNormTallMan = a.RxNormTallMan,
                                      AgentNccnTallMan = a.NccnTallMan,
                                      AgentName = a.Name,
                                      AgentVersionKey = a.VersionKey,
                                      Added = t.Added,
                                      Modified = t.Modified,
                                      Agents = GetAgentsByTemplateId(t.Id).ToList(),
                                      Indication = t.Indications,
                                      Indications = t.Indications
                                                    .Select(v => v.Content)
                                                    .Where(v => v != null && v != "")
                                                    .Distinct()
                                                    .OrderBy(v => v)
                                                    .ToList(),
                                  })
                                  .OrderBy(t => t.TemplateIdMain)
                                  .ThenBy(t => t.TemplateIdNumeric)
                                  .ThenBy(t => t.TemplateIdAlt);

    var result = TemplatesJoinAgentList.GroupBy(p => new { p.TemplateIdMain, p.TemplateIdNumeric, p.TemplateIdAlt }).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();

    return result;

}

